# How to convert Microsoft ODC file/PowerQuery from Excel file with over 2 million rows of data to a CSV file?

Tags: excel, ms-office, export-to-csv, powerquery, data-cleaning

I recently used PowerQuery to clean a dataset with over 2 million rows of data. How can I now save this cleaned dataset as a usable CSV file, not a query? I cannot load the query into excel and then save it as it contains over 2 million rows of data.

Can I save the data connection as a Microsoft ODC file, open it in Access and then save it as a CSV file? Or are there any other alternatives?

NOTE: Essentially my ultimate goal is to upload the dataset into Tableau (to visualize the data). So any solution that enables this would be preferred and appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use DAX Studio to export the table into CSV from the data model or PBI.

https://daxstudio.org/